# Detect Object type then cast it accordingly?

Tags: java, types, casting, object, downcast

My method takes as input an Object. How do i determine it's type, then cast it accordingly?

So for example: `binarySearch( Object o );`

Inside the binarySearch method, i need a way to determine the type (or class) of Object o. Then i need to cast it with that type. how would i do that???

And more specifically, Object o is a child of a base class (EG SalariedEmp is child of Employee), and i specifically need the base class.

EDIT:
I figured out how to do what I wanted, which really should be a completely different question. I needed to use the .compareTo method from `Comparable` to set up a way to compare two objects based on private data from those objects. All i had to do was implement my class as 'Comparable' using the `implements` keyword. So no matter what Type of objects are compared in my binarySearch method, it works if they are of the same (unknown) type and have Comparable implemented. This makes my binarySearch method very re-usable with any type of comparable class.

So, in all fairness, I'll accept the answer that covers the original question.

:)

Comment: Why not make it take an Employee instead of an Object?

Comment: Generally, this is accomplished using the instanceof operator, but if you post some more code, we may be able to help you find a better solution, potentially using generics since it looks as if you may be dealing with a collection.

Comment: "i need... to determine the type..." **why**? When you put instances of a base class into the same container, it's generally to **forget** their derived types. You document that you only care about the fact that they implement the interface of the base type.

Comment: @Etienne de Martel because i want it to be widely useable with different objects, assuming they are Comparable.

@Karl Knechtel well, anywho, i figured it out. I cast everything that goes into my method as Comparable, no matter what it is.. so i make the assumption that whatever object is inputted is comparable to another object of same type... but what if they are not same type?

Comment: So yeah, I'm just trying to make a method that takes Objects so that i can take it out of my class, and put it in my ToolBox class for generic purposes. Example methods would be BinarySearch, QuickSort, etc, etc.... So these methods will work on various different Comparable objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways to do this:

1. Use the `instanceof` operator.
2. Call `getClass()` on the object (make sure to check for null first).

Answer (score 3):

```
if (o instanceof SalariedEmp)
    doSomethingWith((SalariedEmp)o);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use RTTI (Run-Time Type Identification) by using the instanceof operator or by calling .getClass() on the instance, but that's almost always an indication that the super-type you're using is either the wrong super-type, or is badly designed.

In your case, you don't need to be using Object, as you already know that you at least have an Employee.

The Object Oriented paradigm is that you don't ask an object instance *what* it is, you ask it to do something. In this case, you have a choice of several thing you might want to ask an Employee object to do. Which one is the best choice for you depends on exactly what you're trying to model:

You could ask it if it is salaried, and then possibly cast it, by adding a virtual method `boolean isSalaried()` to the Employee base class. The base method would return false, but a SalariedEmployee would override that method and return true.

But while that avoids (the likely more expensive) RTTI, it doesn't avoid the cast. You could add a method SalariedEmployee asSalariedEmployee(), which in the base class would return null and in a SalariedEmployee would return `this`. That gives you a "safe" cast, but you still need a test against null.

Or you could just add a Money getSalary() method to Employee.  Now you don't have to do any casting, but you'd need to decide what the salary of a non-salaried employee is; that could be null, zero, or NaN (the special Not a Number value).

If you decided to return null, in some cases (e.g, adding values) you'd have to test against null, in others (e.g, passing the salary to .equals()) you wouldn't need to test against null, as any instance.equals(null) should return false by the specification for Object.equals().

If you return zero, you can add without testing against null, but equals might be a bit weird -- is it really true that two hourly workers, each of whom get no salary, have the same (nonexistent) salary? That depends on what you're modeling. If it is true, return zero.

If it's not true that two hourly workers have the same non-existent salary, return a NaN value. This is justa specific case of the "Null Object Pattern".

Comment: You're answer provided very nice details, but Mike Baranczak technically provided the correct answer (without all the nice and informative material) before you did. Thank you very much for the awesome info.